# Segfault when using fopen

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am getting segmentation fault when I use fopen function.
if i use `file` not in struct then no error occurs.
i guess the segfault comes from using a `file` from a struct

```
int     main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    t_paint     *paint;

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        write (1, "Error: argument\n", 16);
        return (1);
    }
    paint->file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (paint->file == NULL || parsing(paint))
    {
        write(1, "Error: Operation file corrupted\n", 32);
        free(paint->map);
        fclose(paint->file);
        return (1);
    }
    output(paint);
    fclose(paint->file);
    free(paint->map);
    return (0);
}
```

t_paint

```
typedef struct      s_paint
{
    char            *map;
    int             widthMap;
    int             heightMap;
    float           firstX;
    float           firstY;
    float           w;
    float           h;
    char            typeFile;
    char            background;
    char            filler;
    FILE            *file;
}                   t_paint
```

Comment: You have the pointer `paint`, but ***where does it point?*** Why is it a pointer to begin with? If you need to pass a pointer of the structure to a function, you can easily use the address-of operator `&` to get a pointer to the structure object.

Comment: You need to allocate space for the struct, add `t_paint     *paint = malloc(sizeof(t_point));`

Comment: Or create an instance of the struct, e.g. `t_paint can;` and then initialize the pointer with the address of that instance, e.g. `t_paint *paint = &can;`

Comment: On an unrelated note, why `write (1,...)`? Why not the common `printf(...)`? Using `write` will make your code much harder to maintain (and less portable), especially if you use [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) for the length. What if you need to change the message and forget to change the size? Or miscounted the number of characters?

Comment: Guys, I apologize for my inattention. I really forgot to allocate memory for the paint...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
t_paint     *paint;

if (argc != 2)
{
    write (1, "Error: argument\n", 16);
    return (1);
}
paint->file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
```

You modify the `file` member of the object `paint` points to. But `paint` doesn't point to anything -- you never assigned it a value or created an instance of `t_paint`.